# Where to find Jest __snapshots__ directory

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

It seems like Jest `__snapshots__` folder is automatically created inside `__tests__` folder where you are collecting your tests files. Does anybody know where can I find it in case I am not collecting my tests in `__tests__`?

Comment: Okay I got it. It turns out that I need to manually create it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always created in the same folder as your test is.

So when your test is in `./tests/myApp/Start.spec.js` the corresponding snapshot is in `./tests/myApp/__snapshots__ /Start.spec.js.snap`

Comment: Can we remove the `__snapshot__` folder and have the snapshot in `./tests/mpApp/Start.spec.js.snap` ?